Quarkus CDI failing to find ApplicationScoped bean during quarkus-maven-plugin
I've created a simple Quarkus application that interacts with a backend database, using the repository pattern and a scheduled bean to count the records in the database on a regular basis. During compilation, the quarkus-maven-plugin throws an jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException stating it cannot find the repository, and I can't seem to figure out why. The build of the reproducible example fails with the following error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.12.0:build (default) on project sample-monitor-service: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type com.foo.db.SampleDaoRepository and qualifiers [@Default]
[ERROR]     - injection target: parameter 'sampleDaoRepository' of com.foo.service.SampleManager constructor
[ERROR]     - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.foo.service.SampleManager, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.foo.service.SampleManager]
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1546)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:338)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.initialize(BeanProcessor.java:167)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.validate(ArcProcessor.java:490)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2516)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2495)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1521)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:483)
[ERROR] Caused by: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type com.foo.db.SampleDaoRepository and qualifiers [@Default]
[ERROR]     - injection target: parameter 'sampleDaoRepository' of com.foo.service.SampleManager constructor
[ERROR]     - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.foo.service.SampleManager, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.foo.service.SampleManager]
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:519)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:642)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:323)
[ERROR]     ... 12 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]

I've included a minimal reproducible example, composed of 3 classes. The example is set up with Java 21, and Maven.
Example broken into two projects, as a maven multi-module project. Parent project is sample-monitor, the dao and repository classes are defined in sample-monitor/sample-monitor-db, and the driver class is defined in sample-monitor/sample-monitor-service.
sample-monitor/pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample-monitor</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>sample-monitor-service</module>
    <module>sample-monitor-db</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample-monitor-db</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>

sample-monitor/sample-monitor-db/pom.xml:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample-monitor</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>sample-monitor-db</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                            <artifactId>quarkus-panache-common</artifactId>
                            <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

sample-monitor/sample-monitor-db/src/main/java/com/foo/db/SampleDao.java:
package com.foo.db;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "sample")
public class SampleDao {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

sample-monitor/sample-monitor-db/src/main/java/com/foo/db/SampleDaoRepository.java:
package com.foo.db;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheRepository;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class SampleDaoRepository implements PanacheRepository<SampleDao> {
}

sample-monitor/sample-monitor-service/pom.xml:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample-monitor</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>sample-monitor-service</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sample-monitor-db</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-scheduler</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                            <artifactId>quarkus-panache-common</artifactId>
                            <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.quarkus.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

sample-monitor/sample-monitor-service/src/main/java/com/foo/service/SampleManager.java
package com.foo.service;

import com.foo.db.SampleDaoRepository;
import io.quarkus.scheduler.Scheduled;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class SampleManager {

    private SampleDaoRepository sampleDaoRepository;

    public SampleManager(SampleDaoRepository sampleDaoRepository) {
        this.sampleDaoRepository = sampleDaoRepository;
    }

    @Scheduled(every = "2m")
    public void countAll() {
        System.out.println("Counted " + sampleDaoRepository.count() + " records");
    }
}


Have you tried the project without Lombok... just with a usual class ... apart from that the configuration for the maven-compiler-plugin can be defined in your root pom via pluginManagement without repeating that in each module...

Just tried removing lombok (and updated question with to show code without it), and no changes. Thank you for the suggestion!

Does the sample-monitor-db Maven module include a Jandex index or a[n empty] META-INF/beans.xml file? If not, the bean will not be discovered.

@Ladicek - that was the missing piece, thank you. I tried both mechanisms, putting the beans.xml in with <beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd" bean-discovery-mode="all" version="2.0"/> as the only content, and that worked. I also tried the default maven-jandex-plugin configuration, as described here: https://smallrye.io/jandex/jandex/3.2.0/maven/basic.html. If you put that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you!
